# Best car rental at Corfu (CFU) airport

Tags: car-rentals, greece, recommendations

I'm looking for best car rental option at Corfu. I have gone through numerous sites, reviews and I just cant figure out what is the safest option, because every company I have found, that sites like TripAdvisor said were good, had also many 1* ratings on for example Google Maps, calling each company “scammers”.
I just don't want to get in some pointless argument about some scratch that the staff knew about in advance.
Thanks a lot for recommendations.

Comment: You can always go with big multinationals (Avis, Hertz...), but price shopping is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect yourself against that kind of charge by making sure that any **blemishes** or **missing accessories** are recorded right on the contract, and take some photos yourself for good measure. I found South African rental companies prone to that sort of thing, and I was warned by locals and expats.

And, of course, be careful about adding new scratches from your driving or parking habits. European rural roads can be narrow with scratchy vegetation on the sides, and parking spots can be tight. Comfort level with various insurance coverage options varies with the person (as do the options available). Some places insist on putting a goodly fraction of the value of the car on your credit card if you supply your own insurance, for example.